# Group by in t-sql not displaying single result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

See the image below. I have a table, tbl_AccountTransaction in which I have 10 rows. The lower most table having columsn AccountTransactionId, AgreementId an so on.  Now what i want is to get a single row, that is sum of all amount of the agreement id. Say here I have agreement id =23 but when I ran my query its giving me two rows instead of single column, since there is nano or microsecond difference  in between the time of insertion.
So i need a way that will give me row **1550 | 23 | 2011-03-21**

[image]

**Update**

I have update my query to this

```
SELECT  Sum(Amount) as Amount,AgreementID, StatementDate
FROM         tbl_AccountTranscation
Where TranscationDate is null
GROUP BY AgreementID,Convert(date,StatementDate,101)
```

but still getting the same error

> ```
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'tbl_AccountTranscation.StatementDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> ```

Comment: Please see edited answer - the SELECT clause was fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your group by clause is in error

```
group by agreementid, convert(date,statementdate,101)
```

This makes it group by the date (without time) of the statementdate column.  Whereas the original is grouping by the statementdate (including time) then for each row of the output, applying the stripping of time information.

To be clear, you weren't supposed to change the SELECT clause

```
SELECT  Sum(Amount) as Amount,AgreementID, Convert(date,StatementDate,101)
FROM         tbl_AccountTranscation
Where TranscationDate is null
GROUP BY AgreementID,Convert(date,StatementDate,101)
```

Comment: Another quick answer needed on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376407/how-to-convert-value-to-specific-date

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a Group By StatementDate.

In your example you have 2 StatementDates:

> 2011-03-21 14:38:59.470
>   2011-03-21 14:38:59.487

Change your query in the Group by section instead of StatementDate to be:

> Convert(Date, StatementDate, 101)

Comment: If i remove statement date, then it gives me error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tbl_AccountTranscation.StatementDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to

```
Group by (Convert(date,...)
```

instead of the StatementDate

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  You need to combine your two approaches. This should do it:

```
SELECT  Sum(Amount) as Amount,AgreementID, Convert(date,StatementDate,101)
FROM         tbl_AccountTranscation
Where TranscationDate is null
GROUP BY AgreementID,Convert(date,StatementDate,101)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never need the time, the perhaps you need to change the datatype, so you don't have to do alot of unnecessary converting in most queries. SQL Server 2008 has a date datatype that doesn't include the time. In earlier versions you could add an additional date column that is automatically generated to strip out the time companent so all the dates are like the format of '2011-01-01 00:00:00:000' then you can do date comparisons directly having only had to do the conversion once. This would allow you to have both the actual datetime and just the date.

Answer (score -1):

You should group by DATEPART(..., StatementDate)

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: which part would you recommend/

Comment: Probably second. It depends on how your records are introduced.